# Java error: cannot find symbol .hasNextInt()

Tags: java

I am getting an error where I can't compile my code due to:

> error: cannot find symbol
>
> while(numbers.hasNextInt()) {
>
> symbol:   method
>
> hasNextInt()   location: variable numbers of type String

I believe it has something to do with the String but I'm not quite sure.

```
//Takes a string of numbers, adds them together, and gives average

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Section6HW {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

      //intro
      System.out.println("Enter a string of numbers with spaces between numbers");
      System.out.println("to signify the end of a number.");
      System.out.println();

      //input
      System.out.print("Enter numbers: ");
      String numbers = console.nextLine();

      //processing
      int sum = 0;//priming loop
      int count = 0;
      while(numbers.hasNextInt()) {
         count++;
         sum += numbers.nextInt();
         System.out.println("sum of " + count + " = " + sum);
      }
      System.out.println("average = " + (sum / count));
   }
}
```

I know there are a couple of unnecessary pieces of code in this but disregard that, it's for further development.

Comment: number is a String; there's no hasNextint() method on that class.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
numbers.hasNextInt()
```

to

```
console.hasNextInt())
```

You need to call the `hasNextInt()` method on the `Scanner` object, not a on a `String`.

Comment: Also, `numbers.nextInt()` -> `console.nextInt()`.

Comment: Sure, but, he gets the point. Though I highly advise you @Alex to check the JavaDocs.